# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.ITokenAcquisition' while attempting to activate graph api

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory

net core 2.2 project. I am implementing groups based authorization for my apis. I followed https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/886f2ad2bf6add922c7998fb592e3d4088f9cf4e/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-2-Groups to implement this. First I added https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/886f2ad2bf6add922c7998fb592e3d4088f9cf4e/Microsoft.Identity.Web to my project. Then I started adding policy in my startup.cs as below.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("GroupsCheck", policy =>
                    policy.Requirements.Add(new GroupsCheckRequirement("2a39995a-8fd1-410e-99e2-11cf6046090d")));
            });

            services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, GroupsCheckHandler>();
```

Then I added GroupsCheckHandler.cs

```
public class GroupsCheckHandler : AuthorizationHandler<GroupsCheckRequirement>
    {
        private readonly ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition;
        private readonly IMSGraphService graphService;

        public GroupsCheckHandler(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition, IMSGraphService MSGraphService)
        {
            this.tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
            this.graphService = MSGraphService;
        }
        protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                  GroupsCheckRequirement requirement)
        {
            string accessToken = await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenOnBehalfOfUserAsync(new[] { Constants.ScopeUserRead, Constants.ScopeDirectoryReadAll });

            User me = await graphService.GetMeAsync(accessToken);

            IList<Group> groups = await graphService.GetMyMemberOfGroupsAsync(accessToken);

            var result = false;
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                if (requirement.groups.Equals(group.Id))
                {
                    result = true;
                }
            }

            if (result)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }

        }
    }
```

Then I added authorize attribute in api as below.

```
[Authorize(Policy = "GroupsCheck")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
```

Now when ever I try to access any api I am getting below exception.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.ITokenAcquisition' while attempting to activate 'LocationServicesAPI.Services.GroupsRequirements.GroupsCheckHandler'.
```

Can someone help me to figure out what might be the root cause of this issue or If I have done it wrongly or any configurations missing can someone help me in this regard. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Just an update, Microsoft.Identity.Web is now a NuGet package. We encourage its usage to keep your library updated and with bug fixed. [Microsoft.Identity.Web wiki](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki)

Answer (score 14):

The dependency injection is trying to instantiate an instance of ITokenAcquisition and failing. This could be because of an issue with the configuration in Startup.cs. You need to ensure you have the calls to **EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi** and **AddInMemoryTokenCaches** while configuring Authentication.

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration, "AzureAd")
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Comment: What library is `.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()` contained in? As my IDE can't find it. I'm guessing it's in the same as `.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi` because I can't find that either. I'm using .Net 5.0 and the documentation around how to obtain and use tokens is, as usual, beyond poor.

Comment: Both are in microsoft.identity.web

Comment: `EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi` does exist but requires parameter with an Action. Such example should be provided for a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

You might have missed these lines on you `Startup.cs`:

```cs
services.AddSignIn(Configuration);

services.AddWebAppCallsProtectedWebApi(Configuration, new string[] { "YourApiScope" })
   .AddInMemoryTokenCaches(); // Or .AddDistributedTokenCaches(); depending on which token cache provider from Microsoft.Identity.Web you would like to use.
```

The DI registration for `ITokenAcquisition` happens inside `AddWebAppCallsProtectedWebApi` method, on Microsoft.Identity.Web.

Answer (score -4):

I had an error almost like that using Blazor and resolved it by changing services.AddScoped() to services.AddHttpClient()